# Xamarin Forms - display naive contact selection UI (android & ios) and get selected contact back to xamarin forms page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an app where in one screen it has to popup contact selection, then user will select a contact (perhaps click on it) and the contact information will be passed back to the xamarin forms page to fill out the form. I am using visual studio.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin

Comment: I endup creating my own page in PCL and using the contact plugin. thanks